# PhpStorm - can you "collapse to level" without recursion?

Tags: phpstorm, folding

One feature that I miss from Visual Studio (and which I've never seen anywhere else) is "collapse methods" or something like that. In essence, you collapse method (function) bodies and **ONLY** function bodies. That is, if there is an `if` statement inside that function, it DOESN'T get collapsed. So that when you expand the function body, it ALL gets expanded.

In PhpStorm you can collapse starting at level X (which would work), but it then also recursively collapses everything below that level, which isn't what I want at all. I just want to collapse all methods at their top level so that I can see a class with its method names, and then when I click a particular method to expand, I want it all to get expanded and see the full source.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: AFAIK Notepad++, PhpEd also can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not currently possible  . Maybe some custom plugin... but I'm not aware of such.

Watch these and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133161 (the screenshots there with proposed actions is what I  would like to see to be implemented)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167045
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178318

P.S. IDE has `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding --> Fold by default` but at the same time it does not provide an action to re-apply that folding on request (separate action that can be invoked at any time). It's https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80100

---

The best you can do here is:

1. Use "Collapse All"
2. Click on `[+]` for each method when needed with <kbd>Alt</kbd> key pressed (this will recursively expand/collapse all sub levels). Or use a keyboard shortcut (`Code | Folding | Expand Recursively`).